# Installing Sonata Admin with Symfony 2.8 and PHP 7.2

Tags: composer-php, sonata-admin, php-7.2, symfony-2.8

I have an existing (and working) Symfony 2.8 project with Sonata Admin. It used to be installed on a server with PHP 5.6, but I have to move it to a server running PHP 7.2.

For some reason my `composer.json` was not in sync with its `composer.lock` so I'm trying to fix that but I'm lost in a dependency hell. Hoping someone here has a working setup similar to mine :)

I have a bunch of dependencies, but here are the ones that seem to be the culprits:

- `sonata-project/admin-bundle`
- `sonata-project/block-bundle`
- `sonata-project/core-bundle`
- `sonata-project/datagrid-bundle`
- `sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle`
- `sonata-project/intl-bundle`
- `sonata-project/user-bundle`

I used to have them in `2.2.*@dev`, `2.3.*@dev` or `2.4.*@dev` but I now get conflicts when I require them this way. I eventually got a valid composer.lock with this config (notice I removed `block-bundle` because it is required by one of these):

```
"sonata-project/admin-bundle"             : "2.3.10",
"sonata-project/datagrid-bundle"          : "^2.2.1",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.2.8",
"sonata-project/intl-bundle"              : "^2.2.4",
"sonata-project/user-bundle"              : "^2.2.5",
```

But the admin part of the site is broken with the following error:

```
Variable "sonata_admin" does not exist
```

I also got `Block "preview" on template "SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig" does not exist` at some point, but can't remember when/how.

I know Sonata has a long history of making Composer dependency a complicated thing (because of its multiple packages and versions), and I've read numerous questions/issues on Stack Overflow and GitHub but couldn't find the one for me.

Has anyone found the perfect combination of requirements?
Would love to know!

Comment: Please share more details - how is the given Twig error related to Composer itself?

Comment: I know this is weird, but this requirements' combination yields no Composer error, but leads to this Twig error when browsing the admin of the site.